# Is it better to remove a user's preferences after they log out?

Tags: mobile-application, settings, first-impression

We have some preferences for our mobile application that a user can change (such as choosing between miles and kilometers for distance information).  We plan to store these preferences as unique to a user (meaning that if the user logs out, and someone else logs in, the preferences are reset to the default).

**The question is, if that first user were to log back in, should we show their originally-set preferences, or revert to the default?**

Is there such thing as an assumption that preferences are meant to be cleared on logout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the general assumption is not that preferences are meant to be cleared. I'd say that the opposite is the case: when you need to log in to use an application, you expect the application to remember you when you return.

A few considerations:

**User expectation** - most users expect personalisation and a constant experience - especially in the mobile domain it is important that you can continue where you left.

**Predict what the user wants** - in the case of miles vs kilometers there is very little chance that a user's preference will change from one day to another so it makes sense to keep the settings across sessions. There might be other situations where a user needs a one-time exception to the normal settings - but in that case this should not get stored in the preferences at all.

**Privacy and security** - for sensitive information there might be strong reasons to restore the empty slate more often.

Answer (score 2):

For preferences like these, I would always set them once (preferably when a user signs up/logs in for the first time). So, once a user has set his preferences, he gets to see everything using those, every time he logs in, unless he makes a change to those preferences.

For long-lived preferences, as a user, it would get annoying pretty quickly to have to make the same defaults over and over again. There are no assumptions, as far as I know, that a user's preferences must be cleared on logout.